# Virtualbox - cannot create COM object

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am getting the error

> Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object. Runtime error opening '/opt/VirtualBoxVMs/VirtualBox.xml for reading -38 (Access denied)

for other users apart from root. If I login using root, I am able to start VirtualBox.

The problem is this occurs in one of the lab machines and I don't want to change permissions or reinstall VirtualBox without getting to know about the error better. I want to replicate the error in my testbed and then I need to make the changes.

Comment: what are the permissions on that file?

Comment: There is no permission on that file.

Comment: If I run the command "getent group vboxusers", I am able to see all the users listed under the group vboxusers. However, only the VirtualBox.xml file seems to be not having the permission. Why is this error happening?

Comment: There are permissions applied to that file:  run `ls -l /opt/VirtualBoxVMs/` from the command line.  Specifically we want to see the read/write/execute bits and the owner and group(usually in the first 4 columns of output).